# Is there any common Mail Notifier available for Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, email, google-chrome-extensions, notifications

I have a mail account provided by my company which is on a private domain. There is no options for mail notification in that domain. Others asked to use Microsoft Outlook for notification features and all. But I want to access from Google-Chrome only.

Is there any extension where I can provide my mail id with password so that it can notify me for new mails? We are using IMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this tool: [Chrome WebMail Notifier](http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/)

Your question doesn't state what protocol you're using (POP3, IMAP, Exchange)... The link I've sent does

```
Gmail (Gmail & Google Apps)
Yahoo (yahoo.com, ymail.com, yahoo.co.jp)
Hotmail (hotmail.com, msn.com, live.com)
AOL (aol.com, aim.com, mail.com)
Daum (daum.net, hanmail.net)
Naver
Nate (nate.com, empas.com)
Paran (paran.com, hanmir.com)
POP3/IMAP
```

You get all the options you would expect:

[image]

And just for completeness: [Firefox WebMail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webmail-notifier/)

Comment: Mail account is in **Network solutions** which uses IMAP

Comment: In that case, this will work. Original post edited.

Comment: I installed X-Notifier extension. But don't know to configure. Which option should I choose from the list?

Comment: Select IMAP. As for your actual settings to enter, try http://www.networksolutions.com/support/pop-imap-settings/ to get your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Realizing that this is a very old question/answer, I'll regardless provide a correction (since this still comes up on Google searches).

Unlike its counterpart for Firefox, the X-Notifier plugin for Chrome does *not* support IMAP.  (But if you happen to have RoundCube webmail installed on your IMAP server, there is a "Webmail Notifier" plug-in available for that along with a script for X-Notifier.  This works quite well also on Chromebooks, and once configured, allows you to access Roundcube without having to manually log in).

Sorry, no solution for Exchange, and no solution for plain IMAP on Chrome.